# Unable to log into sql database

Tags: sql-server

I set the mode to mixed and created a login for sql server, e.g sql_login_user.
This works and i am able to login to the server and database with the sql_login_user.

I then created a user in the database (readonly_user) and assigned them the "sql_login_user" login. I also selected SQL user with login. The schema was default (dbo).

However, when I try to connect with the user name readonly_user, I get an error - "login faile for user readonly_user..."

I'm fairly certain this worked for me in SQL Server 2014.

ANy help would be appreciated

Comment: You can't login with database users. For starters, they don't have a password or any kind of authentication mechanism. You can only login with server logins - SQL Logins with usernames and passwords, or Windows(/Active Directory) Logins.

Comment: thank you. just realised what i was wanting and doing were two different things.